# Connect to EC2 via Midnight Commander with key pair

Tags: amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I can connect or copy files to EC2 machine via:

`ssh -i my.pem ec2-user@ec2.xxx.compute.amazonaws.com`

and

`scp -i my.pem file.txt ec2-user@ec2.xxx.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user`

but I want to manage remote files via Midnight Commander. There are "shell links" but how can I use it with key pair connection?

Comment: Related: [Using sftp on non-standard ports with `mc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29419/209677)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> There are "shell links" but how can I use it with key pair connection?

Put the following into `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host ec2.xxx.compute.amazonaws.com
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile /path/to/the/my.pem
```

then try again.

Comment: Excellent! And I can use host alias in `Host` attribute and real host name in `HostName` attribute. Nice. Thanks quanta.

Comment: How is this working again? I'm adding the config file to /.ssh/config and then how will I use it in Midnight Commander?

Comment: Totally agree with Softy - then what should I do? I thought that it must detect my.pem file by those settings above for this particular user, when I'll try to connect say - myuser@ec2.xxx.compute.amazonaws.com in Shell Link via mc, err - couldn't chdir.

Answer (score 7):

Other way. Enter in console:

```
ssh-add /path/to/your/key/file_name.pem
```

After that you can enter your_name@your_address.amazonaws.com in mc shell-connect menu and press Ok

Comment: That was easy, thanks. Still works in 2021

Comment: And it still works in 2024.